# Деепричастные обороты и пассивные конструкции

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, грамматика, деепричастный-оборот

Почему так можно

> Получив признание широких читательских масс, книга была в фаворе.

а так нет

> Получив признание широких читательских масс, книга была переиздана.

Субъект здесь один и тот же (книга) и совершает одно и то же активное действие (была)

Потом на это активное действие навешивается страдательное причастие, но к стандартной конструкции деепричастие+глагол+субъект причастие уже не имеет отношения. Мало ли что там еще навесили на основной каркас.

И что насчет допустимости

> Получив признание широких читательских масс, книга была популярна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При нулевой связке **быть** становится понятна нелепость использования деепричастий вместе с пассивом:

```
Получив признание читательских масс, автор уволен на покой.
```

При деепричастии несовершенного вида, также очевидна нелепость:

```
Постоянно опаздывая на работу, автор был уволен.
```

Если деепричастие совершенного вида, но нет причинно-следственной или временной связи с основным действием, то все также возникает диссонанс:

```
Покурив немного в сторонке, автор был уволен.
```

Суммируя сказанное, стоит лишь измениться связке быть, виду деепричастия, или причинно-следственной связи и конструкция деепричастие + пассив рушится:

```
Опоздав на работу, автор уволен.
Опаздывая на работу, автор был уволен.
Покурив немного в сторонке, автор был уволен.
```

Кто-то, возможно, скажет, что дело может быть в семантической сочетаемости. Но нет, это не так, потому что уже с семантическим пассивом фразы звучат прекрасно:

```
Опоздав на работу, автор увольняется.
Опаздывая на работу, автор уволился.
Покурив в сторонке, автор уволился.
```

Таким образом, дело в грамматике - в неправомерности именно синтетического пассива с деепричастием. Единственное исключение можно сделать, когда удовлетворяются сразу три замысловатых условия. Тогда возникают примеры-исключения, приятные для слуха, но не вписывающиеся в общую грамматическую картину.

```
Прийдя на работу, автор был уволен.
```

Answer (score 2):

Действие, обозначаемое деепричастием, должно относиться  к подлежащему данного предложения, причем речь идет о **реальном** действии.

Поэтому **пассивные** конструкции, в которых это правило соблюдается только по грамматической форме, а подлежащее **не является субъектом действия**, не отвечают норме.

Например:

***Получив признание широких читательских масс, книга была переиздана.*** Фактически на слух это воспринимается как такой вариант: *Получив признание широких читательских масс, книгу переиздали.*

Розенталь: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm

**Не отвечает норме** употребление деепричастного оборота в **страдательной конструкции**, так как производитель действия, выраженного сказуемым, и производитель действия, выраженного деепричастием, не совпадают, например: «*Получив признание широких читательских масс, книга была переиздана*».

Надо полагать, что это правило относится **к любым страдательным конструкциям:**

*Получив признание широких читательских масс, книга была популярна.*

Вариант редактирования с использованием причастного оборота: *Эта книга, получившая признание широких читательских масс, еще долгое время была популярна.*

Comment: 1. "Быть популярной" - это страдательная конструкция? "Быть красивой" - тоже страдательная?

Comment: По семантике - да, книга не совершает активных действий. Предложение воспринимается как стилистически некорректное. Деепричастный оборот обозначает активное действие предмета, который  его совершать не может. Это пассивный предмет: книгу признают,  книгу делают популярной. Есть понятие субъекта действия, вот книга таким субъектом действия не является, хотя имеет функцию подлежащего.

Comment: Кстати, это мое мнение. В ответе оно имеет специальную метку "надо полагать". В этом месте я уже не цитирую Розенталя, а даю свою оценку. Мне предложение кажется стилистически некорректным. В то же время я с интересом выслушаю все другие точки зрения, особенно альтернативные. То есть тех, кому это предложение нравится. Разные мнения - это всегда интересно.

Comment: Как насчёт "Получив признание читателей, книга стала самой популярной в своём жанре (и затем многократно переиздавалась)"? Розенталь не называет свой пример ошибкой, но похоже, вынужден был сослаться на формальную норму (нельзя "страдательности" даже при живом подлежащем), которой тот "не соответствует".

Comment: Хорошо, что хотя бы "стала", а не "была". Страдательность может хорошо замаскироваться, так что пользователи перестанут ее замечать. Но чтобы приветствовать такие предложения, хотелось бы послушать мнение лингвистов, а также  убедиться, что хорошие писатели используют их в книгах. Так постепенно и вернемся в 19 век (к галлицизмам и народной речи).

Comment: И еще. Книга была популярна, книга была издана... Какая разница? В том, что именная часть выражена кратким прилагательным или кратким причастием? Но ведь даже действие иногда называют предикативным признаком, в отличие от признака качественного. На слух нам без большой разницы, была ли книга популярна или издана, а вот то, что она как бы куда-то приходит и что-то получает,  несколько напрягает слух.

Answer (score 1):

Полностью  **сохраняет свою актуальность**  следующее утверждение Розенталя:

«**Не отвечает норме** употребление деепричастного оборота в страдательной конструкции, так как производитель действия, выраженного сказуемым, и производитель действия, выраженного деепричастием, не совпадают, например: «Получив признание широких читательских масс, книга была переиздана».

Понимать его надо так.  Субъект действия (издатель) и пассивный объект действия (книга) не могут участвовать в построении деепричастных конструкций, когда **объекту действия приписывается функция субъекта действия.**

**Именно это «режет слух» и воспринимается носителями языка как явная ошибка.**

**Мы не пуристы** и совершенно свободно относимся к переносному значению слов: дождь может идти, хотя у него нет ног, а книга может получить награду, как будто это реально действующее лицо. Да, в отдельных предложениях мы представляем **неодушевленному предмету право быть субъектом действия**, но только не в предложениях с деепричастными оборотами.

Получить признание – это всего лишь стать признанный (иметь  соответствующий признак), здесь нет никакого активного действия. Во всех приведенных в вопросе примерах надо использовать **причастные,** а не деепричастные конструкции:

*Получившая  признание широких читательских масс, книга долгое время была в фаворе.
Получившая  признание широких читательских масс, книга была переиздана дополнительным тиражом.*

Comment: Вы задавали вопрос с предложением "Глядя на него, Мечику невольно захотелось всё рассказать самому..." Я снова запутался. Так можно или нет относить деепричастие к таким "лично-безличным" (о, новый термин!) предложениям? Вроде лицо есть, но не в им. падеже, и не оно захотело, а ему захотелось. Я так понимаю, что строгая грамматика не позволяет так писать, а семантика разрешает, примеров предостаточно, и у классиков тоже?

Comment: Александр, а у Розенталя рассматриваются безличные предложения:  В безличном предложении при инфинитиве, например: Приходилось работать в трудных условиях, НЕ ИМЕЯ в течение многих недель ни одного свободного дня для отдыха. Предложение безличное,  да только  в сказуемом основное содержание передает ИНФИНИТИВ, а он относится к субъекту действия (к тем, которые работали и не имели отдыха). То есть нам очень важна семантика, которую мы воспринимаем на слух, а не грамматика.  Субъекты действия в предложении и деепричастном обороте должны совпадать.

Comment: Глядя на него, Мечику невольно захотелось всё рассказать самому..." Здесь оба действия  (глядит, хочет рассказать) совершает один субъект, хотя грамматическим подлежащим он не является. Поэтому предложение корректно.

Comment: Очень спасибо! Понятно.

Comment: Точно понятно, а то вот некоторые участники не согласны со мной.

Comment: Да, я вспомнил, что это есть в правилах, про инфинитив. А не согласны по этому же вопросу или, как я вижу, по текущему, который относится к пассивным конструкциям?

Answer (score 0):

Между двумя вариантами, приводимыми в вопросе, я не усматриваю никакой разницы. На мой взгляд, правомерность применения подобной конструкции зависит от того, признает ли автор за "книгой" (неодушевленным предметом) право выступать субъектом действия или нет. Если да, то оба варианта имеют право на существование. Ср., напр., "[переиздающиеся книги](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%22&hl=en)" и "[переиздаваемые книги](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%22&hl=en&sxsrf=AOaemvJ0S3sxruEsYZJkJFBv8eaXviRfDA%3A1634042555861&ei=u4JlYfX4M-PrrgTtsJSgDA&ved=0ahUKEwi1wtvw8sTzAhXjtYsKHW0YBcQQ4dUDCA4&oq=%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAw6CggjEK4CELADECdKBAhBGAFQ1d4QWPjvEGCgghFoAXAAeACAAVuIAfAEkgEBOJgBAKABAcgBAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz)". Второй вариант, конечно, более правильный, но мы нормально воспринимаем конструкцию "книга получила награду", хотя, разумеется, книга сама ничего получить не может, а может лишь быть удостоена награды (которую на самом деле дают писателю, а не книге). Если нет, то и тот и другой вариант будут резать ухо пуристу.

Answer (score 0):

Не могу согласиться со столь широким обобщением данного правила с приведенного примера на все случаи жизни. А если предложение будет следующим: "Пропустив два дня без уважительной причины, я был уволен за нарушение трудовой дисциплины"?  Мне это предложение представляется вполне приемлемым, а вот это нет — "Пропустив два дня без уважительной причины, меня уволили за нарушение трудовой дисциплины".

Comment: Не могу понять, с чем вы не согласны. Первое предложение корректно,  Субъект действия один и тот же, он же является грамматическим подлежащим. Второе предложение неверно:  там субъект действия в деепричастном обороте (я)  не совпадает с субъектом действия в основном предложении (они).

Comment: А что насчет предложения "Покуривая, я был уволен за курение". Понимаете откуда ноги растут у данного правила? Вовсе не из неодушевленности субъекта. "Покурив, я был уволен" - совсем другое дело. И конечно, Sharon опростоволосислась с субъектами действия. Они разные. Человек был уволен, субъект действия - внешние люди. Но с этим субъектом бесполезно говорить, учитывая уровень продемонстрированной логики

Comment: Добрый день, давно не виделись.   Я не понимаю ваших примеров.  Предлагаю работать  с  нормальным грамматическим материалом (как люди говорят), тогда и объяснимся.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Как корректно? Вы же процитировали Розенталя: "Не отвечает норме употребление деепричастного оборота в страдательной конструкции, так как производитель действия, выраженного сказуемым, и производитель действия, выраженного деепричастием, не совпадают". Производитель действия, выраженного деепричастием, - это я, а действия, выраженного сказуемым, - администрация. Ср.: "Пропустив два дня без уважительной причины, я уволился, опасаясь быть уволенным за нарушение трудовой дисциплины." - вот здесь все действительно синтаксически чисто.

Comment: "Первое предложение корректно" - примечательно, что Вам оно показалось корректным. Я задал аналогичный вопрос (Правильно ли построены предложения "Опоздав на работу два раза на неделе, я получил выговор за нарушение трудовой дисциплины." и "Пропустив два дня без уважительной причины, я был уволен за прогулы."?) на mail.ru, и все ответившие согласились, что правильно, хотя по этому правилу только первое его не нарушает - но и в нем фактические (не грамматические) субъекты разные: опоздал я, а выговор сделала мне администрация.

Answer (score 0):

Таким образом, поскольку Sharon признал корректным предложение "Пропустив два дня без уважительной причины, я был уволен за нарушение трудовой дисциплины.", то оба исходных примера в этом вопросе следует расценить как эквивалентные и правильные, а правило о согласовании субъектов действия в деепричастном обороте и главном предложении - как надуманное и ненужное. Очевидно, что необходимо лишь явное, однозначное и корректное ("я", а не "меня", "мне" и т.п. в данном контексте) согласование между субъектом действия, выраженного деепричастным оборотом, и подлежащим главного предложения для построения синтаксически правильного предложения. Все ответившие на мой аналогичный вопрос (Правильно ли построены предложения "Опоздав на работу два раза на неделе, я получил выговор за нарушение трудовой дисциплины." и "Пропустив два дня без уважительной причины, я был уволен за прогулы."?) на otvet.mail.ru, признали их правильными. Следует также отметить, что подобного правила нет ни в английском, ни во французском языке, так что требование соблюдения столь скрупулезной, схоластической логики при синтаксическом оформлении подобных высказываний не отвечает современной речевой практики носителей языка. Считаю, что здесь - как и во многих других случаях - следует придерживаться правила [KISS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF)) - Keep it simple, stupid.

Comment: В русском языке, тем более у Розенталя, не бывает совершенно надуманных правил. Каждое правило основано на конкретных речевых ситуациях. Вот и здесь можно придумать очевидно-корявые речевые обороты, которые и закрываются данным правилом. К примеру: "Покуривая, я был уволен". -- Что это такое?? Правило говорит нам, что это чушь, и языковой опыт подтверждает!

Comment: По-латински такой довод называется "argumentum ab auctoritate" - якобы авторитет не может ошибаться. Розенталь может ошибаться. Например, он одобряет использование прописных букв в терминах типа "Высокие Договаривающиеся Стороны" (http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=30) - хотя это всего лишь ошибка переводчика, не знающего правил русского языка и слепо следующего оригиналу (High Contracting Parties).